# Old name showing when I send/receive messages

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, stack-overflow-jobs

I linked my Google Account to my Stack Overflow account a long time ago, when my Google account had a different name.

I've since changed my name on both Google, and on my profile on Stack Overflow, but my old name is still persisting in messages.
When I look at the email addresses linked to my account it just shows my email address and doesn't show the name associated with the account. Red parts are where it says my old name:

[image: Red parts are where it says my old name]

Is this a bug, and should it instead be showing the name from my profile? Is there a way to change this name, or update the reference to my current Google account name?

Comment: Looks like the name from your developer story; that name is used in favour to the one from your profile. We know this sucks, it's being worked on to make it suck less.

Comment: The name on my Developer story is not the (old) name that's appearing in my messages though :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can update the name visible to employers [on your dev story](https://stackoverflow.com/users/story/current).

1. Click the edit button in the first section (the one  with your profile picture).

*Note: to display the edit button, either hover the first section (desktop) or tap it (mobile)*

[image]

2. Update the "Full Name" field

[image]

Comment: I tried the link, and the only option was "edit profile and settings", from there there was just my display name, and real name (private), none of which are the name I see in the messages

Comment: @ECH What you describe doesn't match what I see on my end. Could you please send me an email (agasser@stackoverflow.com) with screenshot of 1. what you see when you click https://stackoverflow.com/users/story/current 2. what you see when you click "edit profile and settings"?

Comment: @ECH Please see my updated answer. The "Edit" button gets displayed .by hovering/tapping the first section on your dev story